# What do the different color hit splats in Diablo 3 represent?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was playing Diablo 3's new season, and realized that there are 3 different types of hit splats (white, yellow, and orange).

[image: Example image]

I think white is a regular hit, and yellow is a critical hit, but I am not sure what the orange represents.

What do the hit splats mean in Diablo 3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like you already said - White is regular damage and Yellow is for critical hits.

Orange numbers represent your highest crit in the last few seconds.
This is the algorithm for calculating what crits are worthy of showing in orange:

> - Damage numbers must be over 10,000 to be considered
> - If the damage number to be displayed is larger than the last that was    displayed in orange, then display this new number in orange
> - Decay the value of the largest number by 3% every second. This reduces the likelihood that you’ll go on too long without seeing any
>     highlighted numbers
> - Ignore the first 10 large numbers. This allows for the system to calibrate itself
> - If no damage has been dealt for 10 seconds, reset the system

[Source](https://www.diabloii.net/blog/comments/diablo-3s-damage-display-detailed)